# Comparing two strings of integers and printing out a match

Tags: java, string, integer

Let's say these are my two strings

```
String listOfIntegers = ("1 5 9 12 15 50 80 121");
String integerToLookFor = ("12");
```

I want my program to scan listOfIntegers and print out if integerToLookFor is in the string.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Split the string with space as a delimiter to get an Array of Strings.
2. Scan the Array and check every element if it is equal to the lookup variable.

Code:

```
String listOfIntegers = ("1 5 9 12 15 50 80 121");
String integerToLookFor = ("12");
String[] splitArr = listOfIntegers.split("\\s");
for(String s: splitArr){
    if(s.equals(integerToLookFor)) {
        System.out.println("found: " + s);
        break; //breaks out of the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would split the list into string array and then using foreach loop i would find the match by comparing the values.

Answer (score 2):

If you ensure that both the list and the number to search for are enclosed in spaces, you can simplify the search:

```
    String listOfIntegers = " " + "1 5 9 12 15 50 80 121" + " ";
    String integerToLookFor = " " + "12" + " ";
    if (listOfIntegers.indexOf(integerToLookFor) != -1) {
        // match found
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Arrays;    
String listOfIntegers = ("1 5 9 12 15 50 80 121");
String integerToLookFor = ("12");    
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(listOfIntegers.split(" ")).contains(integerToLookFor));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array ints = listOfIntegers.split(' ');
print ints.inArray(integerToLookFor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matcher and Pattern.compiler in the regex package.
See the example below:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(integerToLookFor);
Matcher m = p.matcher(listOfIntegers);
while(m.find()){

   System.out.println("Starting Point:"+m.start()+"Ending point:"+m.end());

}
```